# Downsaving ArcGIS Package to older version

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am trying to make a package of a project in ArcGIS Pro for some colleagues to work on. They are using shared computers and so have limited ability to update the computer programs or software. While some have computers that open the package without problems, others are getting an error about the computer being an older version and the layers will not load (they all have exclamation marks). I cannot for the life of me figure out how to downsave the file to an older version on my computer. Is there a way to do this and still package the file? Or is there another workaround that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

The [Package Map geoprocessing tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/package-map.htm) allows you to package to an earlier version of Pro.  [And here is some online help](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-import-an-arcgis-pro-project-to-arcmap-000023367#:%7E:text=Open%20ArcMap%2C%20and%20sign%20in,geodatabase%20used%20in%20ArcGIS%20Pro.) about getting a Pro project into ArcGIS v10x